# Getting positions of a line renderer on moving and rotating a line

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry

I have a line with line renderer attached to it . **The user can move the line and rotate it.** How do I go about getting the new positions of the line renderer which has been moved or rotated? since the coordinates of vertices of line renderer do not change , only the positions and the rotation of the line object as a whole changes .

[image: ScreenShot of line object]

**The positions in the bottom part of image do not change on moving or rotating it.** These positions are returned by the getpositions() method which is not useful in my case.

Comment: Please, this is not a duplicate question . I want to get the new positions of the line renderer after movement or rotation of the object . getpositions method does not produce these results.

Comment: You can use @username to reply to people when the question is closed.I luckily ran into your edit and comment again.

Comment: Thank you for the info and removing this question as a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) in unity takes a list of points (stored as [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html)s) and draws a line through them. It does this in one of two ways.

1. **Local Space**: (Default) All points are positioned relative to
   transform. So if your GameObject moves or rotates, the line would
   also move and rotate.
2. **World Space**: (You would need to check the Use World Space
       Checkbox) The line will be rendered in a fixed position in the
       world that exactly matched the Positions in the list. If the
       gameObject moves or rotates, the line would be unchanged

So what you really want to know is
**"How do I get the world space position of a local space point in my line?"**

This common use case is addressed by methods on a gameObjects transform

[Transform.TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

It takes a local space point (which is how the data is stored in the line renderer by default) and transforms it to world space.

**An Example:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LineRendererToWorldSpace : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer lr;

    void Start()
    {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        // Set some positions in the line renderer which are interpreted as local space
        // These are what you would see in the inspector in Unity's UI
        Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[3];
        positions[0] = new Vector3(-2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
        positions[1] = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        positions[2] = new Vector3(2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
        lr.positionCount = positions.Length;
        lr.SetPositions(positions);
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        Vector3[] positions;
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        var numberOfPositions = lr.GetPositions(positions);
        //Iterate through all points, and transform them to world space
        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPositions; i += 1)
        {
            positions[i] = transform.TransformPoint(positions[i]);
        }

        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }
}
```

This code is just for demonstration purposes, as I am not exactly sure of the use case. 
Also, my links are to 2018.2 which is a very recent version of unity, however the logic and methods used should be quite similar going back.

Comment: Although the positions are changing on using InverseTransformPoint the documentation states that this method is used to convert a point  from world space to local space

Comment: You are right, I got it mixed up with Transform.TransformPoint. I changed the answer to show the correct method.The two methods are used to go back and forth from local and world space.